# aggregating data in power bi query editor

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have gone through this tutorial

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-tutorial-analyzing-sales-data-from-excel-and-an-odata-feed/

and was having some issues at Task 4 - Step 1 that I have somewhat resolved but would like to find a better way to complete the task.

The issue of this is that the title of my graph is Sum of UnitsInStock by ProductName but I just want it to be "UnitsInStock by ProductName".

See image below:

[Sum of UnitsInStock by ProductName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOHWn.png)

I think the issue is that in the tutorial link it has the "UnitsInStock" column is aggregated already (which you can see in the field pane) whereas I had to aggregate the data myself. I think to fix this I just have to aggregate the data in the query editor but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The button you want is **Group By** - it's on the **Home** ribbon in the central **Transform** section.

Select your grouping columns before hitting it, to preload them in the **Group By** window.  I haven't followed that tutorial so you will need to decide what to select. Any column you don't select for **Group By** or aggregate (see below) will be removed by this Step.

In the bottom section of the **Group By** window, click the **+** button to add an aggregation, then choose **Sum** and choose your column (e.g. **UnitsInStock** ). You have to type the output column name.